# Attempting to install FBLuaLib

Tags: build, lua, compiler-errors, deep-learning, torch

FbLuaLib: https://github.com/facebook/fblualib

To install FBLuaLib, I need to install thpp: https://github.com/facebook/thpp

I can build folly, fbthrift just fine, but when I run ./build.sh for thpp I get the following error message:

```
Linking CXX executable tensor_serialization_test
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libthriftcpp2.so: undefined reference to `virtual thunk to folly::AsyncSSLSocket::closeNow()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libthriftcpp2.so: undefined reference to `virtual thunk to     
folly::AsyncSSLSocket::getRawBytesWritten() const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libthriftcpp2.so: undefined reference to `virtual thunk to 
 folly::AsyncSSLSocket::setEorTracking(bool)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libthriftcpp2.so: 
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libthriftcpp2.so:    undefined reference to `virtual thunk to 
folly::AsyncSSLSocket::performRead(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libthriftcpp2.so 
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 test/CMakeFiles/tensor_serialization_test.dir/build.make:95: recipe for 
target 'test/tensor_serialization_test' failed
make[2]: *** [test/tensor_serialization_test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:240: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles
/tensor_serialization_test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/tensor_serialization_test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:123: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```